# Stringify macro values in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm developing in XCode 4.2, and was wondering how I could stringify macro parameters? I was trying to use `#` as I thought I would do in **C**, but to no avail. Here is my macro:

```
#define ASSIGN_PROPERTY(PROP_NAME, PROP_NAME_PARAM) { \
  if (PROP_NAME_PARAM == nil) { \
    NSAssert(PROP_NAME != nil, @"#PROP_NAME is already nil"); \
    PROP_NAME = nil; \
  } else { \
    NSAssert1(PROP_NAME == nil, @"#PROP_NAME is already set, address=%p", PROP_NAME); \
    PROP_NAME = PROP_NAME_PARAM; \
  } \
}
```

Then in a class that has `foo` as a property, I define its setter like so:

```
- (void) setFoo:(NSObject *)fooParam {
  ASSIGN_PROPERTY(foo, fooParam)
}
```

Say a client calls `setFoo` with a non-nil value, but the `foo` property is already non-nil. I want the macro to print:

> foo is already set, address=0x5e55400

But instead it's printing:

> #PROP_NAME is already set, address=0x5e55400

Any advice?

Comment: why not just use @property (assign)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a macro that can take a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793882/how-to-make-a-macro-that-can-take-a-string)

Comment: @bryanmac I want to assert if I attempt to assign a non-nil value while `foo` is already non-nil, or assign a nil value while `foo` is already nil. Using `@property(assign)` will just blindly overwrite the value in either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like

```
NSAssert(PROP_NAME != nil, @"%s is already nil", #PROP_NAME);
```